# ionic 2 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I just tried to

> RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:163:2)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)
>       at deepClone (C:\Users\Adir\MyApps\ToDoApp\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:165:18)

this is my adminPage, this pages makes the problem

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

import {Storage,LocalStorage} from 'ionic-angular';



/*
 Generated class for the Admin page.

 See http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/components/#navigation for more info on
 Ionic pages and navigation.
 */

@Component({
  selector: 'page-admin',
  templateUrl: 'admin.html'
})
export class AdminPage {
  data: any;
  local: Storage = new Storage(LocalStorage);
  public getsession:any;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
    this.data={};
    this.data.title="";
    this.data.desc="";
    this.local=new Storage(LocalStorage);
    this.local.set('session','true');

    this.getsession=this.local.get('session');
    this.getsession.then((value)=>{
      let x=value;
      console.log(x);

    })


  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {

  }

}
```

Comment: can you please share your admin.html?

Comment: <ion-header>

  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title>Admin</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>


<ion-content padding>

</ion-content>